# When I add a margin to a nested DIV, it causes the parent DIV to receive the margin instead, unless I give the parent DIV a border. Why?

Tags: css, html, parent-child, margin

Has anyone else ever ran across this? This is the second time it's come up in as many years and I am not sure the "correct" way to solve it.

I can achieve the same results with padding in the child, but it just makes no sense.

Testing in Safari/FF.

Comment: i think this is the correct behavior; it's all to do with the CSS box model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually solve this problem by setting `display: inline-block` on outer div. It'll make outer div to occupy exactly the space necessary to display its content.

[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuBU7/), showing the difference.

Answer (score 4):

It is called margin-collapse. When a top and bottom margin are directly touching (not separated by anything, like a border or line break) the margins collapse into a single margin. This is not a bug. Read more about it here at [SitePoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like margin collapsing which is natural behaviour. This is a good read:

http://www.andybudd.com/archives/2003/11/no_margin_for_error/

> > > There are number of ways to get round margin collapsing issues. One way is to add a border 
> > >       or 1px of padding around the elements so that the borders are no longer touching and so no 
> > >       longer collapse.
> > >
> > > Another way to stop margins collapsing is to change the position property of the 
> > >       element.The CSS2 Specs explain that margins of absolutely and relatively positioned boxes 
> > >       don't collapse. Also if you float a box it's margins no longer collapse. It's not always 
> > >       appropriate to change the position properties of an element but in some situations if 
> > >       you're having problems with unwanted margin collapsing, this may be an option.